# How to input/output & compare "long long" variables in C?

Tags: c

I wrote a program in C. My purpose is testing how "long long" variables work. But the resule comfuse me.
My OS : WinXP
My compiler: TCC (Tiny C Compiler) http://bellard.org/tcc/   version 0.9.25
========   My Source code   ========

```
# include "stdio.h"
# include "math.h"
void main() {
 long long n,i;
 scanf("%lld",&n);
 i=42;
 printf("\nn=%lld",n);
 printf("\ni=%lld",i);
 printf("\ni<=n --> %d",i<=n);
 return;
}
```

========   The End of Source Code  =========
Run the program, I input:

```
30
```

Then, the output is:

```
n=30
i=42
i<=n --> 1
```

**It means " i(42) is smaller than n(30)". Why?**
Is there any mistakes when I input a long long variable?
**Can you show me the right way?**
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens if you just set n to 30, rather than scanf it in?

Comment: I get the expected "0" result on my Linux system with GCC. Perhaps some tcc issue ?

Comment: Works fine for me too (i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 and Apple clang version 1.6). BTW, `main` should always return `int`.

Comment: If `tcc` is linking to the Microsoft libc, that's likely your problem. I believe modern versions of mingw have replaced/fixed Microsoft's broken `scanf` and `printf`, but if not, switch to cygwin.

Comment: It works for me (gcc 4.3.4). Have you tried another compiler?

Comment: Thank you everyone! I get it! I should use printf("%I64d", var) and scanf("%I64d", &var) instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First, write your `main()` as

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

Or, as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv) { /* ... */ }
```

And then, probably you need a **better** compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `printf("%I64d", var)`

Comment: No, you should get an updated/fixed library or abstract this nastiness behind a wrapper...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get it! I should use printf("%I64d", var) and scanf("%I64d", &var) instead. Thank you!